# ASP.NET ModelState Errors $. in KeyValue

Tags: asp.net, .net-5, webapi

My model has a property DateOfBirthUtc which is of type DateTime and has an attribute [Required]. When I post this model with an invalid DateOfBirthUtc (empty) to my action method, I get an expected error.

What I don't understand is why the error in the key/value pair that ModelState produces is called "$.dateOfBirthUtc" what does the "$." mean and why is it added to the key?

```
{
    "type": "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.1",
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "00-6999b89fb406304fbc11a17676de581a-5b59646fda25f248-00",
    "errors": {
        "$.dateOfBirthUtc": [
            "The JSON value could not be converted to System.DateTime. Path: $.dateOfBirthUtc | LineNumber: 4 | BytePositionInLine: 22."
        ]
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the root of your JSON, it show your property position in the JSON object from the root

Comment: Thanks! This link was also helpful: https://help.talend.com/r/en-US/Cloud/api-tester-user-guide/jsonpath

But i still don't know why ModelState some times returns error keys like the json key "$.dateOfBirthUtc" and with other errors the c# property name "DateOfBirthUtc".

Comment: I think when it return with $ that's an issue of converting the JSON to your class, but when it's a C# property it's already been converted fine but the requirements for this property is not meet