ASP.NET Core - Custom ModelBinding Error Messages
I have an ASP.NET Core Web API project, with a controller and a controller method that has a parameter [FromBody] MyDTO dto.
When I call this method via REST request with an empty body, the framework returns a ProblemDetails object with something like this:
{
  "type": "https://xyz/Status-400",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "errors": {
    "": [
      "A non-empty request body is required."
    ]
  },
  "trace-id": "..."
}

which is absolutely understandable.
But: when I call it with a request body like "[]" which is not a jsonObject but an array (whereas the controller method needs a single object), the ProblemDetails response object looks something like this:
{
  "type": "https://xyz/Status-400",
  "title": "Bad Request",
  "status": 400,
  "errors": {
    "$": [
      "The input was not valid."
    ]
  }
  },
  "trace-id": "..."
}

which again is somewhat "okayish" if one can assume that $ means request body (this message comes directly out of the ModelStateDictionary).
My questions are:

How can the name of the key $ be changed?
Should it be changed?


$ signifies the root of the JSON document - it cannot and should not be changed - it's a well-known, well-understood element of JSON

As this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/69783628/11147346
said  $ key in the error response from the ModelStateDictionary represents the root of the JSON document. if you would like to change this
You could try customize error:
Filters/ValidationFilter.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using System.Linq;

namespace CustomErrorResponseAPI.Filters
{
    public class ValidationFilter : IActionFilter
    {
        public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
        {
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var problemDetails = new ProblemDetails
                {
                    Type = "https://xyz/Status-400",
                    Title = "Bad Request",
                    Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
                    Detail = "The input was not valid."
                };

                var errors = context.ModelState
                    .Where(x => x.Value.Errors.Count > 0)
                    .ToDictionary(
                        kvp => string.IsNullOrEmpty(kvp.Key) ? "requestBody" : kvp.Key,
                        kvp => kvp.Value.Errors.Select(e => e.ErrorMessage).ToArray()
                    );

                //if (errors != null)
                //{
                //    problemDetails.Extensions["errors"] = errors;
                //}

                context.Result = new BadRequestObjectResult(problemDetails);
            }
        }

        public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) { }
    }
}

Program.cs:
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using CustomErrorResponseAPI.Filters;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers(options =>
{
    options.Filters.Add<ValidationFilter>();
});
builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
{
    options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
});
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


